# Select only visible or any properties else element in variable

Tags: jquery

My English isn't strong so I'll explain the question by the code.

```
function (jQelem1) {
  jQelem1.[select_only_visible].each( function () { doSomething(); });
}
```

Is it possible to select only **visible or any properties** else element in variable.

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jQuery](http://jquery.com) has [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible) selector for us.

```
function (jQelem1) {
  jQelem1.filter(':visible').each( function () { doSomething(); });
}
```

**To check for any other properties with visibility**

Suppose:

```
// check for presence of id
function (jQelem1) {
  jQelem1.filter(':visible[id]').each( function () { doSomething(); });
}

// check for presence of class
function (jQelem1) {
  jQelem1.filter(':visible[class]').each( function () { doSomething(); });
}

// check for both presence of id and class
function (jQelem1) {
  jQelem1.filter(':visible[id][class]').each( function () { doSomething(); });
}

// check for both presence id = foo
function (jQelem1) {
  jQelem1.filter(':visible[id="foo"]').each( function () { doSomething(); });
}

// check for both presence id = foo and class=bar
function (jQelem1) {
  jQelem1.filter(':visible[id="foo"][class="bar"]').each( function () { doSomething(); });
}
```

And many more. Read about **[jQuery selectors clearly](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)**.

Answer (score 1):

```
function (jQelem1) {
  jQelem1.filter(":visible").each( function () { doSomething(); });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`function (jQelem1) {

    jQelem1.filer(":visible").each( function () {
doSomething(); });  }`

or whatever property you want